# Manga where main character is reborn by a goddess and tried to be assassinated by his father?

Tags: story-identification, manga

Searching for a manga about a boy who is reborn by a goddess with a cheat skill, but his father thinks he is useless and sends the mother and child to remote area to kill the boy when he gets old.

Answer (score 1):

Fuguushoku To Baka Ni Saremashita Ga Jissai Wa Sorehodo Waruku Arimasen?
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not sure how this matches the question; can you describe the scene you're showing us?

Comment: the main character will be killed right on the main character's birthday, previously the main character already knows and plans to escape...

i hope you can understand what i write